# How do I pass a collection of object types to a function as a parameter in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
function Get-OSInfo {
    param([string]$Computer)
    $OS = gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $Computer
    $OS | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name OSType –Value ""
    $OS.OSType = Get-OSType -Input $OS
    write $OS
}

function Get-OSType {
    param([?]$Input)
    if ($Input.ProductType -eq 1) {
        write "Client OS"
    }
}

$blah = Get-OSInfo -Computer mypc
$blah | fl *
```

I realize that this could be done with a single function (or in the body of the script itself), but I have simplified the functions to highlight the trouble I'm having. What I want to do is pass the gwmi dataset from the Get-OSInfo function as a parameter variable in the Get-OSType so I can reference all of its properties in the second function without passing them individually from the first. Clear as mud?

I have tried multiple parameter accelerator types, `[ref]`, `[array]`, `[object[]]`, etc., but I haven't found anything that works as a parameter. The only thing that has proven to work is to change the second function to use `args[0]` for accepting input, but that is not as clean as using parameters, and since it works, I can't help but think there is a parameter that should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `$input` as that has special meaning in functions (representing pipeline input).  Just rename the parameter to something like `$OS`.

The docs (man about_automatic_variables) on `$input` say:

> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is
>   passed to a    function. The $input variable is available only to
>   functions and script    blocks (which are unnamed functions).  In the
>   Process block of a    function, the $input variable enumerates the
>   object that is currently    in the pipeline. When the Process block 
>   completes, there are no objects    left in the pipeline, so the $input
>   variable enumerates an empty    collection. If the function does not
>   have a Process block, then in the    End block, the $input variable
>   enumerates the collection of all input to    the function.

Comment: Wow. I feel like a dunce. Thank you Keith. Changing away from $Input worked!